# Is it possible to choose an input scope for Actionable notifications

Tags: uwp

I have textbox in my toast notification to receive user input. Is it possible to choose the `InputScope` of the textbox to show a different keyboard, like a numeric keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no such [`InputScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscope) property of [`ToastTextBox`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/api/microsoft_toolkit_uwp_notifications_toasttextbox),You could only use default keyboard for inputting message. If you need this new feature please feel free to ask for this feature on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).

Comment: Thanks! I added my request